# Azure-Cloud asp.net mvc Session Timeout 20 min

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, azure

We are currently running a ASP.NET MVC Application within the Microsoft Azure-Cloud.
The problem is, that – after a user login – the session will time out after `20 min`
I've tried to increase this time via form `authentication timeout` and `sessionState` in the `web.conf` – unfortunately without any effort.

Here is how I tried to change the timeout:

web.config - form atuh

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" timeout="2880" slidingExpiration="true" />
</authentication>
```

web.config - sessionState

```
<system.web>
    <sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="UseDeviceProfile" timeout="180" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    ...
```

And Global.asax:

```
void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Code that runs when a new session is started
        LinksSuggestions.SetLinksSuggestions();

        // Set Session timeout to 180 minutes
        Context.Session.Timeout = 180;
    }
```

Like I said, unfortunately nothing worked. The user gets kicked right after 20 minutes...

Is there anything I have missed? I do not even know, which timeout will be used if e.g. defined in Global.asax and web.config...

Comment: I don't know about azure many things but do you use iis? if yes change session time out from there.

Comment: I think azure's IIS will use the time defined within web.config because I have no direct access to the IIS node file (I am not 100% sure about this.)

Comment: For simple asp.net or mvc iis for sure uses session timeout. But for azure unfortunately i don't know.

Comment: Okay, but thx anyway! Maybe somebody else has some hint for me concerning the cloud...

Comment: Does it work on your "local" IIS ?

Comment: to be honest, haven't tried it always in staging which means in the cloud only but I'll try it locally and give u an update (might take a while cause I'm not in the office)

Comment: May it be that the application pool is inactive for a long period of time and gets recycled? May it be that the transport connection to that specific instance of IIS is closed and then the client reconnects to another instance that has no idea of who the user is?

Comment: @sharptooth this is IMHO the most likely reason for the timeout. Do you have any suggestions on how to solve this issue without using any client script sending NOPs to the server?

Comment: @Alexander: Well, even with NOPs this won't always work because if the TCP connection is broken the client will reconnect to some random instance. You have to either use some persistent shared storage for the session data or put it into the cookie and expect the user to send it to you on each request.

Comment: @sharptooth okay I get that, but doesn't my web.config input with the sessionSate element (<sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="UseDeviceProfile" timeout="180" />) set this cookie if supported/possible on client side (UseDeviceProfile)

Comment: @Alexander: Maybe, but trying to rely on "session state" module in Azure is not a good idea anyway so I wouldn't even try.

Comment: @sharptooth all right, great thanks for your help. I'll try to force the cookie if possible and/or try NOPs until somebody may have a better solution on this issue...

Comment: @Alexander did you ever find a solution to this problem? I m stack at the same spot. I ve tried all the above and more but nothing worked. I m also hosting my app on azure.